# Why only 1 of 4 core have 100% usage on ubuntu?

Tags: cpu, htop

I've got problem with my usage when I'm on ubuntu 20.04 becasue my 3rd core in CPU have 100% when I'm doing nothing when I'm playing YouTube everything is lagging I have i5-7500 3.4 GHz and 16GB RAM, below Screenshot of my problem. How can I solve this thing?[my_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxlSf.png)

Comment: Does closing "Discord" gets rid of the CPU use?

Comment: nope, closing Discord doesn't help